# Rails page not change when javascript file changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I change a javascript file in Rails,and refresh the page,but not change.

why? I even restart the server.but still not work.

this situation caused just when I execute the command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: look in your public folder if there are assets, if so, delete them

Comment: I am sure I have deleted the `assets` folder in `public`,but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `/config/environment/development.rb` and this will work in DEV mode, for production mode you should pre-compile assets and turn off this setting.

So only for DEV mode

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true
```